# How to find areas under the normal curve?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, descriptive-statistics, scipy

I was able to draw a normal curve using the data samples in Python with the help of `import scipy.stats as stats` library as:

```
normal_curve = stats.norm.pdf(dataset, mean, std_dev)
```

where mean was 100 and standard deviation = 5.

From this how can I find the area between two points say, 95 to 100? If I am correct, the whole area is 100% and 50% of the area lies on left of '100' and 50% on the right.

[image]

Right now, this graph isn't very useful until I can find how many values lie in a certain amount of area, so is this calculated using some function? It will helpful if it can be shaded as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the definition of a CDF $F_X$ for a random variable $X$:

> $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X\le x)$

For an absolutely continuous pdf $f_X$ such as the normal distribution, we have $$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt $$.

So if we want to know the probability between $a,b$ s.t. $a<b$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b f_X(t) dt &= \int_{-\infty}^b f_X(t)dt - \int_{-\infty}^a f_X(t)dt \\&=F_X(b)-F_X(a).\end{align}$$

Scipy implements the normal CDF, so all you have to do is subtraction:
`scipy.stats.norm.cdf(b, loc=mean, scale=sd)-scipy.stats.norm.cdf(a, loc=mean, scale=sd)`

Comment: Thanks. I think this solved it. Is area under normal curve always 1 regardless of whether I use frequency or probability distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. All probability distributions have total probability of 1.

Comment: I see. Can I check this sum? e.g. `normal_curve.sum()` adding all the numbers didn't give me '1'.

Comment: Why would it? A probability *density* function gives the *density* at a point, not the probability in an interval. Taking a Riemann sum where the limit of polygon width goes to zero show the connection between sums and certain integrals. Considering this fact should make it clear why summing finitely many values of a density doesn't give a correct answer: you need infinitely many rectangles. This bring us back to the cdf $F_X$.